How to pass arguments containing parentheses to aws ecs execute-command using python subprocess.run?
Goal: Use the aws cli in a subprocess.run call to execute a command in a container of a running task.
Example Usage:
task_arn = 'a_task_arn'
arg = event = {'something': 'that contains ( )'}

# Attempt 1: json string
arg = json.dumps(arg)
subprocess_cmd = 'aws ecs execute-command --command "python -m task.function {arg}" --interactive --task {task_arn} --container Container'
subprocess.run(subprocess_cmd, shell=True

# Attempt 2: encoded json string
arg = json.dumps(arg).encode('utf-8')
subprocess_cmd = 'aws ecs execute-command --command "python -m task.function {arg}" --interactive --task {task_arn} --container Container'
subprocess.run(subprocess_cmd, shell=True



Encountered Error: /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
I am trying to use the cli through a subprocess.run call instead of using the boto3 execute_command because

it doesn't appear that there is an easy way to read the websocket boto3 returns: https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/3496,
as indicated in this SO answer, it only returns a very small portion of the websocket message: How can I get output from boto3 ecs execute_command?


If you ran the same python -m task.function b'{"something": "that contains ( )"}' command directly on your computer, or in a locally running docker image, do you get the same error? I suspect you simply need to add some escape characters to the command input, but it's impossible to know without seeing the actual command you are trying to run.

Using subprocess.run to pass arguments containing parentheses to python scripts works fine using either a json string or an encoded json string. I think I tested the same using docker exec and it worked but will try to reproduce that. So far it seems to be an issue only when using the aws cli.

I am able to pass in both a json string and the encoded version when using docker exec on my local machine.

Am I reading this wrong, but are you not actually showing us your subprocess.run() call? The "attempted solutions" are showing us strings, but not Python code that tells us what you're doing with those strings. Make sure you're showing a [mre] -- code complete enough that we can use it to cause the same problem ourselves without needing to make changes or additions.

The actual call is either of the attempts passed to subprocess.run(subprocess_cmd, shell=True). I will update the question though.

The full command needs to include the aws ecs execute-command ... but I will try out your suggestions.

The big advantage that subprocess has over os.system is that it lets you pass an explicit argument vector, so you don't need to worry about how a shell is going to parse your command. Where you can't take advantage of that, Python provides shlex.quote() to convert a string into code that any POSIX-compliant shell will evaluate into that same string.
import json, shlex, subprocess

task_arn = 'a_task_arn'

arg = {'something': 'that contains ( )'}
arg_json = json.dumps(arg)

# to locally run the command we could subprocess.run(remote_argv)
remote_argv = [ 'python', '-m', 'task.function', arg_json ]

remote_str = ' '.join([shlex.quote(s) for s in remote_argv])

local_argv = [
  'aws', 'ecs', 'execute-command',
  '--command', remote_str,
  '--interactive',
  '--task', task_arn,
  '--container', 'Container'
]
subprocess.run(local_argv) # WITHOUT shell=True


This ended up working for me. The only clarification I could suggest to the post is that --interactive, --task, task_arn, --container, and Container conceptually are grouped with the aws ecs command but it works either way.

@CogitoErgoSum, hmm -- that should cause practical problems (aws ecs execute-command won't parse arguments within the --command as arguments to execute-command itself). Fixing it either way.

My point wasn't clear, I was able to get it to work based off your answer but I implemented how your edit is now. I didn't try the other way. I'm not sure if the other way would actually work.
